# Picturebox not being updated from a subform

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a general idea of what is not happening but is suppose to:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWTqN.png]

The two circled images/pictureboxes should synchronize whenever i update the URL field there. But that doesn't work. What i want is that the image should change whenever i click the "Done" button.

I use Profile.settings file feature to save the profile picture string(Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE). I debugged and find out that my Setup.Settings file have the value loaded in both the scripts but "form_menu" don't update the mini picture.

Here is my initialization code of main form (form with tiny circular picturebox)(where i want the picture to load).

```
public form_menu()
{
    selectedTab = 4;

    InitializeComponent();

    label2.Text = Profile.Default.USERNAME;
    MessageBox.Show(Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE);
    try
    {
        pictureBox4.Load(Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE = Setup.Default.AVATAR;
        pictureBox4.Load(Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE);
    }

    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, pictureBox4.Width - 3, pictureBox4.Height - 3);
    Region rg = new Region(gp);
    pictureBox4.Region = rg;

    pictureBox2.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox2.Location.X - (Profile.Default.USERNAME.Length + pictureBox2.Size.Width) * 3), pictureBox2.Location.Y);
    pictureBox3.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox3.Location.X - (Profile.Default.USERNAME.Length + pictureBox3.Size.Width) * 3) + pictureBox2.Size.Width, pictureBox3.Location.Y);
}
```

"Setup.Default.AVATAR" is another .settings file holding a default image URL in case the user defined one does not load.

Here is my sub form when i upload the picture and press "Done" button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!valid_image)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no image to upload to your profile.", "Upload rejected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    if (textBox1.Text != Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE)
    {
        Profile.Default.PROFILE_PICTURE = textBox1.Text;
        Profile.Default.Save();                
    }

    this.Hide();
    form_menu form = new form_menu();
    form.Activate();
}
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with this: `form_menu form = new form_menu();`  Did you intend to show this *new* form?

Comment: Actually it calls the initial form, so "form_menu" is called and the content in it is loaded. It is suppose to load the avatar image but i don't.

Comment: It's creating a *new* initial form that never gets used.

Comment: Yes, i realized that and i actually have a usage. Edited the first post.
I might be doing it wrong, but i intend to refresh the already opened form so that the image(s) get loaded.

Comment: That doesn't work.  You need a `form.Show();` or a `form.ShowDialog();`  Now you will see that creating a *new* form won't work.

Comment: form.Show(Dialog) shows you a new form and keeps the previous one.

How can i hide the previous one ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have to move your relevant code from out of the constructor.  Something like `public void UpdateAvatar()`, that way you can call it from the constructor, and from your subform.  The subform just needs a reference to that existing form_menu,

Comment: Well, i already tried that and it didn't worked.

`form_menu form = new form_menu();
form.UpdateAvatar(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: I don't know why you keep making a new form.

Comment: Sorry, is there a way to access the old one ?

Comment: Pass the reference.  I can't see where you open this subform, but it would be something like `Subform sf = new Subform(this);`  Then you would have to modify the constructor on your subform `public Subform(form_menu form)`

Comment: Can we do that inline ?

Comment: How can i refer to form_menu which is already opened here. What to put in the first parameter of this when you use this?
`Subform(form_menu form)`

Comment: Which form is opening this subform?

Comment: Its `form_menu` which open `form_upload_avatar`.

Comment: Then it would look like `form_upload_avatar subform = new form_upload_avatar(this);`  Create a variable in form_upload_avatar, something like `parentMenuForm` to store the reference so that you can use it in your button click event.  The line would look something like `parentMenuForm.UpdateAvatar();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I just solved the issue by disposing the original form and then recreating it so everything will be synced.

```
        this.Hide();
        Form form = Application.OpenForms["form_menu"];
        if (form != null)
        {
            form.Dispose();
        }
        form_menu open = new form_menu();
        open.Show();
```

So there will be no need for creating extra variables or callbacks.